Does using Cloudflare to host purely static pages affect Google SEO?
Can a business (B2B) independent website convert WordPress into a static page and put it on Cloudflare static hosting (inquiry using a third-party embedded code communication component)? Will this affect Google SEO results? Do you have any better ways?

Did the URL change?
